# Updating HATEOAS rels

Tags: rest, api-design, hateoas

Let's say I'm shooting for a HATEOAS-compliant API. I provide the endpoint `/cars/{id}`. If a user were to call `GET /cars/12`, they'd see something like:

```
{
    "color": "Red",
    [...],
    "links": [
        { "rel": "driver", "href": "/people/123" },
        { "rel": "owner", "href": "/people/456" },
    ]
}
```

In this model, how do I update a relationship? Like, say the car gets sold to `/people/42`. Does the `PUT` change the value of the `owner` `href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities to do this. This API does not need to be one-to-one data representation, so with that it mind:

- You can modify the resource using `PUT`, even the links if you want
- You can expose a separate "owner" resource for the car, and `PUT` a new owner there
- You could expose an "owned cars" resource from people, and `POST` to that collection, which causes the car to change owners

It depends on how the system is distributed, it may be the case that not all resources are under your control. People could be federated links to third-party resources, in which case they might not have links back to your system, etc.

If everything is under your control, all of the options are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PUT` request can contain the `links` property again for updates. I imagine that the `PUT` request body should near identical to what you received from `GET`, but with an updated owner.

Answer (score 0):

In HATEOAS server should provide links through some hypermedia format (HAL, ...). The client should not create, update or delete those links directly. You should have property owner and driver and the client could update those properties but not links to details for owner or driver. Those links to details for owner and driver should generate server, not a client. The server could change URLs for a resource over time.